# Java: remove all characters after point

Tags: java

I got a quick question,
I got the following code

```
String chapterNumber = "14.2.1";
```

how can I achieve to get a String like the following out of my "chapterNumber"

```
String mainChapterNumber = "14";
```

*Edit:*
I want all the numbers in an int/String (doesn't matter to me) up to the first point

Comment: And did you try something?

Comment: `indexOf()` and `substring()` are your friends.

Comment: I tried sth I found on a forum like: `chapterNumber..replaceAll("//.*$", "");` but that didn't work

Comment: @JamesCarter. You really don't need a regex here.

Comment: the "1" from the start

well actually I need everything split up in a new string up to the first point

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If it's only the first portion of the input string you want, you should do

```
String mainChapterNumber = chapterNumber.split("\\.", 2)[0];
```

The second argument of `split` (`2`) indicates that we should only split on the *first* occurrence of `.`; it's faster than splitting on all instances of `.` which is what would happen if we didn't supply this second argument.

---

**Relevant Documentation**

- [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Just curious about how the memory allocation will be in this case when using split method instead of substring.  Which one would be the best when we parse large strings?

Answer (score 9):

Just use the following:

```
String mainChapterNum = chapterNumber.substring(0, chapterNumber.indexOf("."));
```

This will return a substring of your current chapter number starting from the first character which is placed in index number 0 and ending before the first appearance of "."

Comment: This in fact was a valid solution as well, it worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
String chapterNumber = "1.2.1";
int index = chapterNumber.indexOf(".");
String mainChapterNumber = chapterNumber.substring(0,index);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String mainChapterNumber = chapterNumber.substring(0,chapterNumber.indexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this. 
The easiest one I would recommend is using a substring, and indexOf:
Like this:

```
String result = chapterNumber.substring(0, chapterNumber.indexOf("."));
```

Another way of doing it would be like this:

```
String result = chapterNumber.split("\\.")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have any proof of you actually trying something, I'll make a suggestion instead of giving you code.

Try to play with the indexes of your string. Find the index of the first dot and then use the `substring` method to keep the substring between the origin and that occurence.

Comment: Anyone care to comment the downvote? Is it because I avoided spoonfeeding an OP that shows no sign of effort? I guess so, since a later answer that gives the explicit full code is upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below...

```
String chapterNumber = "1.2.1";
String[] getdt = chapterNumber.split("\\.");
String mainChapterNumber = getdt[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, another solution using [Guava's splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html):

```
String mainChapterNumber = Iterables.get(Splitter.on('.').split(chapterNumber), 0);
```

This has the advantage of not using the regular expression machinery (which is not lightweight, don't use the accepted solution in a loop).