# Java How to split String and delete a part of it?

Tags: java, list, split

I have a list of String `(List <String> titles)` like this:

```
                    "xxxl54.AE",
                    "xxxl56.AP",
                    "xxxl57.AE",
                    "xxxl58.VP",
                    "xxxl59.WR",
                    "xxxl56.SD"
```

But I want to get this:

```
                    "xxxl54",
                    "xxxl56",
                    "xxxl57",
                    "xxxl58",
                    "xxxl59",
                    "xxxl56"
```

How do I delete the part that is to the right of the point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: remove all characters after point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959763/java-remove-all-characters-after-point)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace the strings in your original list:

```
titles.replaceAll(e -> e.split("\\.")[0]);
```

Example:

```
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
titles.add("xxxl54.AE");
titles.add("xxxl56.AP");
titles.add("xxxl57.AE");

System.out.println("Before: " + titles);

titles.replaceAll(e -> e.split("\\.")[0]);

System.out.println("After: " + titles);
```

Comment: Excuse me can you write all the steps ??

Comment: That is just a oneliner. There are no more steps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use combination of default String methods [String.substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) and [String.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

To modify each item of the list, you could use [stream().map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) and to save it again as the modified list [collect(Collectors.toList())](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)

```
List <String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
titles.add("xxxl54.AE");
titles = titles.stream().map(it -> it.substring(0, it.indexOf("."))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But be careful - if one of the items doesn't have a "." in its content, you need to handle it separately:

```
List <String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
titles.add("xxxl54.AE");
titles.add("xxxl00AE");
titles = titles.stream().map(it -> {
    int dotIndex = it.indexOf(".");
    if(dotIndex != -1) {
        it.substring(0, dotIndex);
    }
    return it;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```